# Search Pattern in log

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am trying to get search log file and need to end the search once the string found , i am using below one

```
tail -100 | grep "^$( date +'%Y-%m-%d')" /home/sabari/scripts/log/log.log |grep "Migration status code updated to: S" && pkill -P $$ tail
```

its not kill the search until i manually kill it, can anyone help me?

```
[sabari@mypc log]$ tail -100 | grep "^$( date +'%Y-%m-%d')" /home/sabari/scripts/log/log.log |grep "status updated to: S"
2020-05-19 00:38:27,245  INFO statuslog:? - [P=109585:O=0:CT] status updated to: S
^C
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you want , but just in case if it is :

```
tail -f /home/sabari/scripts/log/log.log | grep --line-buffered ^$(date +'%Y-%m-%d') | sed '/status updated to: S/p;q'
```

This will end the command once the pattern in sed command found.

Comment: its not ending ,

Comment: @sabarinahtan : It should end if the input file is newly added with the string that you are matching in 'sed' command ....if it is already present and you are searching the file for it , then 'tail -f ' is not required . you should use tail -100 <input-file> then...

Comment: yes its working now, after tail -100

Comment: @sabarinahtan : Pleasure ...

Comment: @sabarinahtan If you found the answer useful, please consider [accepting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) it so that others facing a similar issue may find it more easily.

Comment: Solution is fine, but you can also avoid `sed` and stick to grep:  `$ tail -f <logfile.log> | grep ^$(date +"%Y-%m-%d") | grep -m1 -e  "status updated to: S"`

Comment: Yes , we can also do that ...

Answer (score 0):

Your `tail` command is incomplete

```
$ tail -100
```

is trying to read your standard input which is probably not what you want.

Try something like

```
$ tail -100 /home/sabari/scripts/log/log.log | grep ...
```